# Generar varias imagenes con html2canvas y convertir a PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

1. Con la siguiente funcion se puede obtener una parte del HTML para convertir a una imagen y guardar en PDF
2. Pregunta ¿ Cual seria la forma, de tal manera que me permita obtener varios IDs diferentes en document.body y generar varias imagenes y pasar a pdf ?

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            });﻿
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero no sea demasiado tarde, pero tenai el mismo problema y gracias a tu duda lo resolvi de esta manera ->

```
var img1 = '';
var img2 = '';
var doc = new jsPDF();
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#content1")).then(canvas => {
   img1 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   html2canvas(document.querySelector("#content2")).then(canvas => {
      img2 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      doc.addImage(img1, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
      doc.addPage();//aqui hago un salto de pagina, una imagen en cada pagina
      doc.addImage(img2, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
      doc.save('test.pdf');
   });
});
```